# searching for priority Queue (min heap or max heap) in C# , what is efficient structure?

Tags: c#, .net

I am searching for priority Queue (min heap or max heap) in C# , 
is there built in data structure in C# , what's that ? , how is it efficiency ?
tips :
  1-efficient Working with memory
  2-Fast in Insert and  remove

Comment: i want discuss professionally ! not just priority queue !

Comment: But this isn't a discussion board. That's the short way to getting closed.

Comment: implementing data structures that work such as i want not finishing work , PQ must be efficient and implement from fast structures , i have one implementation but it can't satisfay me , i request for yours experience to do that better , or use another best one , please Sharing New implementation and tips

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/optimizing-liststring-performance/9777#9777

Comment: @ L.B : that isn't in C# or clear

Comment: @mojtaba It is c# and just one source file without referencing any external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's my [Priority Queue in C#](http://blog.mischel.com/2007/06/22/priority-queue-in-c/). Also, a lighter-weight version is at [A Generic Binary Heap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).

The second one is more memory-efficient than the first.

Neither is "fast in search." Searching a heap is not an efficient operation. Heaps are designed to quickly insert and quickly remove the first item.

Comment: good implementation , easy to use , and fast.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Comment: @Pangamma Thanks for letting me know. http://www.mischel.com/pubs/priqueue.zip will get you started.

Comment: Alternative for [Priority Queue in C# (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2)

Comment: [WayBackMachine for **Priority Queue in C#**](https://web.archive.org/web/20101227044014/http://blog.mischel.com/2007/06/22/priority-queue-in-c)



[WayBackMachine for **A Generic Binary Heap Class**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160821131547/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789)

Answer (score 0):

I like using the OrderedBag and OrderedSet classes in [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) as priority queues.